# Is there a "stringByReplacingCharactersInRange" method of NSString in Monotouch?

Tags: ios, ios4, nsstring, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

In Apple documentation for [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) there is a **stringByReplacingCharactersInRange** method, however I cannot find this method in Monotouch.

Is this method implementation missing from Monotouch - native API binding?

I need this method to implement some custom string handling logic inside **shouldChangeCharactersInRange**

Comment: Are you using an NSString or a String in MonoTouch?

Comment: I tried both, none has such method.

Comment: not sure what `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` is ? typo ?

Comment: It is an instance method of the UITextFieldDelegate Protocol (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)

Comment: ok, `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` the other string did not return any hit using apple search engine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's some code to do what you need:

```
string text = field.Text;
string result;

result = text.Substring (0, range.Location) + replacement + text.Substring (range.Location + range.Length);
```

Answer (score 5):

Not everything is binded for `NSString` because it would mostly duplicate the .NET methods available in `System.String`.

The easiest way is to work on .NET (native) string and create an `NSString` from them if/when you need to interoperate with API that requires it. This has the advantages of minimizing the number of managed/unmanaged transitions (there's a small cost to that).

```
string s = "...";
var ns = new NSString (s);
```

Same goes if you receive a `NSString` from the API, convert it into a string then manipulate it.

```
NSString ns = NSSomething.GetIt ();
string s = ns.ToString ();
```

If you find a specific binding that has no similar .NET method then please fill a bug report on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and we'll make sure to include it in future releases of MonoTouch. Often an immediate workaround can be given to unblock you.

Comment: Thanks poupou. I cannot find a .NET Framework method equilivent to stringByReplacingCharactersInRange. I will fill a bug report